# Getting this error while installing Phonegap in mac after installing NodeJS?

Tags: android, macos, cordova

I am trying to install Phonegap in my mac after installing Node JS.And I get this error after “sudo npm install -g phonegap”

npm WARN deprecated deflate-crc32-stream@0.1.2: module has been merged into crc32-stream

> ws@0.4.31 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/connect-phonegap/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws
>   (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

Comment: i get the same error ...have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Actually its not an error. Its a warning. I experienced something similar just a while ago:

```
  # npm install -g phonegap
npm WARN deprecated deflate-crc32-stream@0.1.2: module has been merged into crc32-stream
npm ERR! fetch failed http://github.com/component/emitter/archive/1.0.1.tar.gz

> ws@0.4.31 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/connect-phonegap/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
```

I had to manually download http://github.com/component/emitter/archive/1.0.1.tar.gz

```
# wget "http://github.com/component/emitter/archive/1.0.1.tar.gz"
```

And install it:

```
 # npm install -g 1.0.1.tar.gz 
   emitter@1.0.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/emitter
   └── indexof@0.0.1
```

And then ran the command again and still received the warning but it continued after a while and completed the installation:

```
  # npm install -g phonegapnpm WARN deprecated deflate-crc32-stream@0.1.2: module has been merged into crc32-stream

> ws@0.4.31 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/connect-phonegap/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
```

I have just started trying phonegap. I hope you found a way out.

Answer (score 0):

Never figured it out either :-( Workaround:

```
$sudo npm install -g cordova
```

and use Cordova instead.

Answer (score 0):

try Using terminal with the following command

```
$sudo npm install -g cordova
```

to get cordova running on my Mac. You can also use Phonegap Desktop Client.
Download it from their website.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing 0.10x versions of Node.js as it resolved this issue in Windows 8.